# NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 5.0.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

everyone!
I'm trying to add authorization to my app following this example: [ASP.NET Core Web API v3.1: Authorization](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi/01-authorization)

Due to it I'm installing ***Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer***, but I get errors.

My VS IDE version is 16.8.4

Here is my App.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Stripe.net" Version="39.32.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I can't understand, what should I do to solve this problem. Thank you for any advice!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer v5.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/5.0.2) works only with .NET 5. If you work with .NET Core 3.1 you should install lower version of this nuget which is [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer v3.1.11](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/3.1.11).